# Mock rabbitMQ IModel verify error

Tags: c#, unit-testing, rabbitmq

I have a simple unit-test that needs to verify if my method calls the `IModel.BasicPublish` method. So I wrote a simple unit-test:

```
[TestMethod]
    public void RequestAdded()
    {
        const string url = "http://localhost";
        var urlBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(url);

        _proxyService.AddRequest(url);

        _moqModel.Verify(x => x.BasicPublish(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<IBasicProperties>(), urlBytes), Times.Once);
    }
```

However, when I run I get an error:
`invalid verify on a non-virtual member`.

I thought this could only occur when on concrete classes, but not on a interface.

`private Mock<IModel> _moqModel;`

Any thoughts?

Comment: have you tried...
_moqModel.As<IModel>().Verify(x => x.BasicPublish(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<IBasicProperties>(), urlBytes), Times.Once);

Comment: Please check if BasicPublish is an interface member or an extension method. Having BasicPublish as an extension method instead of an actual member could have caused this exception

Comment: Provide [mcve] that can be used to reproduce problem. not enough context in this example as what is currently shown should not cause that error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BasicPublish signature:

```
public void BasicPublish(string exchange, string routingKey, bool mandatory, IBasicProperties basicProperties, byte[] body)
```

Moq and other similar mocking frameworks can only mock interfaces, abstract methods/properties (on abstract classes) or virtual methods/properties on concrete classes.

This is because it generates a proxy that will implement the interface or create a derived class that overrides those overrideable methods in order to intercept calls.

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer. Turns out `RabbitMQ.Client` has a bunch of extension methods like `BasicPublish(this IModel model, string exchange, string routingKey, IBasicProperties basicProperties, byte[] body)` that don't exist on the `IModel` interface.